# Cilostazol (PDE3 inhibitor) for topical weight loss

Tags: body-fat, body-weight, biochemistry

The relative importance of PDE3 inhibitors in lypolysis in human cells is relatively [established](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022227520340347).
The selective PDE3 inhibitor cilostazol is known to be well tolerated by humans, and shows topical effects in [rodent model skin](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0923181194900795).
Moreover, recently a novel approach towards topical application of the specific drug has been [reported](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5840931/).

I was wondering whether a topical application of the drug would have an effect on altering the local biochemistry of adipose  tissue leading thus to topical weight loss.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Regarding your last sentence, are you asking whether any PDE3 inhibitor can be used topically for weight loss, or just cilostazol?  It might be better to narrow down the question to a more focused one, which makes it more likely people to feel comfortable writing a good answer.

Comment: -user1271772 thnx for the suggestion. Edited as suggested